# Titan graph - Multi-datacenter high availability and hot backups - Really? How?

Tags: titan

Sadly I tried to post this question of the titan forum with really no response despite what is mentioned on the titan web site http://thinkaurelius.github.io/titan/.  That is "Multi-datacenter high availability and hot backups."

Well.....how does Multi-datacenter and hot backups with titan, rexster with a ES and hbase datastore work?  There are no docs.

E.g....with hbase...does one use master - slave replication? master-master replication?  What about elasticsearch?  How does  that handle that in a Multi DC with respect to titan?

Any insight will be helpful before I embark on my own solution.

Thanks

Comment: tsk tsk tsk.....when one requests a close..leave a comment.  Do not do a hit and run.

Answer (score 0):

Just to close this loop, as stated by the OP, this question was asked on the aureliusgraphs mailing list and was answered there:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/aureliusgraphs/0nBAONfNJu0

In short, as taken from the answers provided:  Titan relies on the features of the underlying persistence engine for replication, backup and persistence. That gives the user the freedom to choose the persistence engine they know best.